# Adding page number in word header table C#

Tags: c#, ms-word

I have created a 1x3 table as my header in word. This is how I want it to look like.

LeftText          MiddleText                   PageNumber:

I want the PageNumber cell to look like this -

Page: X of Y

I have managed to do cell (1,1) and (1,2). I found this to help me with cell (1,3) but it is not working as I like. I know how to get the total count of the document. I'm not sure how to implement it properly.

```
Range rRange = restheaderTable.Cell(1, 3).Range;
rRange.End = rRange.End - 1;
oDoc.Fields.Add(rRange, Type: WdFieldType.wdFieldPage, Text: "Page Number: ");
```

I can't even get the Text "Page Number: " to display in the cell. All it has is a number right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field enumeration you're looking for is `WordWdFieldType.wdFieldNumPages`.

The next hurdle is how to construct field + text + field as Word doesn't behave "logically" when things are added in this order. The target point remains *before* the field that's inserted. So it's either necessary to work backwards, or to move the target range after each bit of content.

Here's some code I have the demonstrates the latter approach. Inserting text and inserting fields are in two separate procedures that take the target `Range` and the text (whether literal or the field text) as parameters. This way the field code can be built up logically (Page x of n). The target `Range` is returned from both procedures, already collapsed to its end-point, ready for appending further content.

Note that I prefer to construct a field using the field's text (including any field switches) rather than specifying a field type (the `WdFieldType` enumeration). This provides greater flexibility. I also highly recommend setting the `PreserveFormatting` parameter to `false` as the `true` setting can result in very odd formatting when fields are updated. It should only be used in very specific instances (usually involving linked tables).

```
private void btnInsertPageNr_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    getWordInstance();
    Word.Document doc = null;
    if (wdApp.Documents.Count > 0)
    {
        doc = wdApp.ActiveDocument;
        Word.Range rngHeader = doc.Sections[1].Headers[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary].Range;
        if (rngHeader.Tables.Count > 0)
        {
            Word.Table tbl = rngHeader.Tables[1];
            Word.Range rngPageNr = tbl.Range.Cells[tbl.Range.Cells.Count].Range;
            //Collapse the range so that it's within the cell and 
            //doesn't include the end-of-cell markers
            object oCollapseStart = Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseStart;
            rngPageNr.Collapse(ref oCollapseStart);
            rngPageNr = InsertNewText(rngPageNr, "Page ");
            rngPageNr = InsertAField(rngPageNr, "Page");
            rngPageNr = InsertNewText(rngPageNr, " of ");
            rngPageNr = InsertAField(rngPageNr, "NumPages");
        }
    }
}

private Word.Range InsertNewText(Word.Range rng, string newText)
{
    object oCollapseEnd = Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd;
    rng.Text = newText;
    rng.Collapse(ref oCollapseEnd);
    return rng;
}

private Word.Range InsertAField(Word.Range rng,
                      string fieldText)
{
    object oCollapseEnd = Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd;
    object unitCharacter = Word.WdUnits.wdCharacter;
    object oOne = 1;
    Word.Field fld = rng.Document.Fields.Add(rng, missing, fieldText, false);

    Word.Range rngField = fld.Result;
    rngField.Collapse(ref oCollapseEnd);
    rngField.MoveStart(ref unitCharacter, ref oOne);
    return rngField;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! I been stuck for 3 days.