# Interop Word - Insert Mergefield to the End of the Range

Tags: c#, .net, office-interop, com-interop, word-interop

I have this code that inserts fields and words to a range;

```
Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
Document doc = app.Open("FILE PATH HERE");
Range targetRange = doc.Range;
doc.MailMerge.Fields.Add(targetRange, "field1");
targetRange.InsertAfter("between");
doc.MailMerge.Fields.Add(targetRange, "field2");
Debug.WriteLine(targetRange.Text);
```

The output of the code above is;

```
<<field2>><<field1>>between
```

My desired output is;

```
<<field1>>between<<field2>>
```

**How can I make the 2nd field to be inserted at the end of the range** instead of at the start?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding page number in word header table C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57228742/adding-page-number-in-word-header-table-c-sharp) This comes up regularly, the key is to control where the Range is as various kinds of content (and formatting) are inserted, as described in the Answer to the linked question.

Comment: @CindyMeister thank you. I haven't really tried it, but it has the same scenario as mine. I used the aspose library for doing this instead, whenever I insert a field, it inserts at the end of the range by default.